# esper and update listener concurrency

Tags: concurrency, esper

I'm new to Esper and I was wondering if the update method of an UpdateListener is executed concurrently by multiple threads. If that's the case I conclude that write on an HashMap inside this method is not safe. Is it correct, or am I missing something?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you sure they execute cuncurnetly???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reading the documentation currently and it's definitely a good question to ask, since it's not necessarily a yes or no answer but seems like it depends on both configuration and  your implementation.

Check out [Chapter 3: Processing Model](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.5.0/doc/reference/en/html_single/index.html#processingmodel), [Section 13.6: Engine Threading and Concurrency](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.5.0/doc/reference/en/html_single/index.html#api-threading), and [Section 14.4.9. Engine Settings related to Concurrency and Threading](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.5.0/doc/reference/en/html_single/index.html#config-engine-threading).

I would also love to hear of the design choices you made and why.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have time for further investigating how Esper handles concurrency and didn't tune its configuration, so I opted for the safe solution,  I used a ConcurrentHashMap instead of an HashMap.